# setTimeout not working when mouse right click and show context menu

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, settimeout

I try to write a setTimeout function in javascript, and get some problem.
When I use IE, I click the mouse right and show the context menu, the setTimeout stop working.

Here is my code.

```
var t = 30000;
function myTimer(){
    if(t <=0 ){
        console.log('STOP');
    }else{
        setTimeout(myTimer, 1000);
        console.log(t/1000);    
    }
    t-=1000;
};
```

Does anybody have this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have missed to call the `timer` function. try like this.

```js
var t = 30000;
function myTimer(){
    if(t <=0 ){
        console.log('STOP');
    }else{
        setTimeout(myTimer, 1000);
        console.log(t/1000);    
    }
    t-=1000;
};

myTimer()
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with your sample code and I am able to produce the issue.

Here is a testing result.

[image]

Based on my testing result, I find that issue is not related with **setTimeout**. I also tested with this [JS Coundown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_countdown) code example and it produce the same issue.

Issue is that IE pause the execution of JS code while context menu is visible.

It looks like by design and I did not get any solution for it.

As a work around, you can try to disable the right click (only for IE) using JavaScript may help to avoid the issue.